# How can you stop the X4015 warning in a BizTalk solution?

Tags: c#, msbuild, biztalk

I'm getting a number of warnings ...

> warning X4015: symbol 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute' in assembly System.Core is already defined; the first definition is in assembly mscorlib

whilst compiling a BizTalk multiple project solution (some BizTalk projects, some plain C# projects).

How can I stop these as I prefer to have no warnings in a build

**EDIT:** this shows up in VS under the BizTalk output, rather than the Build output

**EDIT:** another datum ... BizTalk solution with two projects (one schema, one maps) compiles without any warning. Add a third project with a single blank orchestration ... the X4015 warning is back. And it's reproducible ... so what is in the File0.cs generated from the ODX XLANGs file?

Comment: Likely more serious issue than "warning" - 4.0/4.5/4.51 target mismatch - search for class name from error to find more details.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Something weird here ... create new BizTalk 2010 solution, with just one project, and add one blank orchestration ... build and I get the X4015 warning!. Checked and the single project is NET 4.0, so how can I get the warning?

Comment: I don't know how this issue is showing up in building that type of solution (never done it myself). Unless someone comes up with an answer - check every assembly involved in the process and see if any are built for 4.5x - project using 4.0 should be getting `ExtensionAttribute` from mscorlib...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov The Microsoft.BizTalk.DefaultPipelines and Microsoft.BizTalk.GlobalPropertySchemas are both runtime version v2.0.50727, the System, System.Configuration and System.XML are v4.0.30319. Double checked and the project target framework is .NET 4.0

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov More data on the effect ... any suggestions?

Comment: crosslinking your MSDN question here : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7d7e5651-c731-4530-8703-8d224e75fff7/warning-x4015-symbol-systemruntimecompilerservicesextensionattribute-in-assembly-systemcore?forum=biztalkgeneral